# Swift,WKInterfaceTimer stops after few minute

Tags: swift, watchos

I want to start the WKInterfaceTimer from past time. Because watch apps stop working in certain time and it could be the time WKInterfaceTimer is working. So I'd like to start it again when the app restarts. To solve this, I made code like below.

```
@IBOutlet var timelabel: WKInterfaceTimer!
override func awake(withContext context: Any?) {
 self.timelabel.setDate(start_time) //start_time is the time WKInterfaceTimer started first.
 self.timelabel.start()}
```

But this code has problem. It works like I expected, but in few min it stops counting up. I don't know why, does anyone have solution?